# What is the atomic explanation for why some materials cannot be magnetized?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrons, atoms

I have heard many variations on the explanation for why certain materials like iron can be magnetized by being stroked with a magnet, but I haven't yet found any source directly explaining why some materials *cannot be* magnetized. I know that in materials that can be magnetized, the atoms inside are like mini magnets because not all of the magnetic fields created by the electrons within the atoms have been cancelled out, because not all of the electrons are paired. So, is the explanation for why some materials (such as cloth) cannot be magnetized that the atoms inside those materials have no overall magnetic field, because all of the electrons generating magnetic fields inside of those atoms are paired, and so all of the fields cancel out? If not, what is the explanation, please?